# Angular Material mat-select not load the initial value

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6

I'm having a problem with the mat-select component, everything works fine but he just not set the initial value when editing... If I change to a simple HTML  everything works fine. I'm doing something wrong?

HTML select that works fine:

```
<select formControlName="category" [compareWith]="compareFn">
    <option [ngValue]="c" *ngFor="let c of categoriesService.categories$ | async"> {{c.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

Angular Material Component that not works as expected:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Category" formGroupName="category" (selectionChange)="setCategoryValueOnForm($event)"
                [compareWith]="compareFn" >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let c of categoriesService.categories$ | async" [value]="c">
        {{c.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

When using the simple select element I see that my function compareFn works, but with Angular Material the 'y' value is always undefined...

```
compareFn(x: ICategory, y: ICategory): boolean {
   console.log(x);
   console.log(y);
   console.log('CALLED COMPARE FN');
   return x && y ? x.id === y.id : x === y;
 }
```

gif with the problem:

[image]
I'm doing something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I was using formGroupName="category" when the correct was formControlName="category"...

```
<mat-form-field hintLabel="select one">
    <mat-select placeholder="Category" formControlName="category"
                [compareWith]="compareIds">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let c of (categoriesService.categories$ | async)" [value]="c">
        {{ c.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error>
      {{ getError('category') }}
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

.ts

```
compareIds(category1: ICategory, category2: ICategory): boolean {
    return category1 && category2 ? category1.id === category2.id : category1 === category2;
}
```